# Magento 2 : Product custom yes_no attribute value not save from admin

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.2

I have added an product yes_no attribute named save_print from admin. It has successfully added and showing in product(admin). When I change the value. Value is not reflecting in back-end.

I have debugged into this and found that attribute value doesn't insert into database. I thought, It may be due to php post_max_size. So I have increased the value of post_max_size to 32M and upload_max_size to 32M but it didn't work. I don't why it is happening. Please help to solve this.

Here is the attribute database
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need create column with name save_print in this table.

> Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
          "save_print ",
          [
          'group' => "",
          'label' => "save_print ",
          'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
          'default' => '1',
          'note' => '',
          'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
          'visible' => true,
          'required' => false,
          'user_defined' => false,
          'searchable' => false,
          'filterable' => false,
          'comparable' => false,
          'visible_on_front' => true,
          'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
          'unique' => false,
          "frontend_class" => "",
          "used_in_product_listing" => true,
          "input" => "select",
          "type" => "int",
          "source" => "Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno",
          'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend'
          ]
      );
    }
}
```

All done, please run the upgrade script `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to install the module and the product attribute sample_attribute will be created. After run upgrade complete, please run php

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works but it shows drop-down instead toggle yes no option. I need toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Continuously 4 hours digging into code, Finally I got the solution. In my case I found there are two table which has same attribute (save_print) record.

Tables are `catalog_product_entity_int` and `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

Both had a record of save_print attribute. As this product have `int` type `backend_type` and value of this attribute update in `catalog_product_entity_int` but fetching the value from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` So I have delete the record of `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and it works fine.